# Получение и проверка формата файлы в input file через js

Tags: javascript, html, файлы, input

Мне нужно, чтобы при выборе файла в `input type='file'` через JS производилась проверка формата файла на соответствие с разрешенными расширениями, и вывести результат - отказ или соответствие.

Вот есть у меня input:

```js
function previevboofileload(ele, id) {
  if (ele.files[0]) {
    var blob = ele.files[0]; // See step 1 above
 var fileReader = new FileReader();
 fileReader.onloadend = function(e) {
   var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
   var header = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   header += arr[i].toString(16);
   }
   alert(header); //Выводит MIME 
   alert(header.length); //Выводит длину - у docx и xlsx она так же 8 хотя символов вижу 6
  if (header == '3c3f786d') {
   alert('fb2');
  } else if (header == '25504446') {
   alert('pdf');
  } else if (header == '24494d41') {
   alert('txt');
  } else if (header == 'd0cf11e0') {
   alert('doc');
  } else if (header == '504b34') {
   alert('docx');
  } else if (header == '504b34') {
   alert('xlsx');
  } else {
   alert(header);
  }
 };
 fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previevboofileload (this,'bookmesage');" name="file">
```

По замыслу, функция должна сверяться с вычислинными MIME и выдавать ответ указан допустимый формат или нет, но сейчас она почему то сравнивает не все (например txt) корректно, даже если ставить строгое равно, как надо сравнивать что бы было правильно?

Как получить в переменную формат выбранного в input файла?

Comment: Посмотрите в консоле file[0] - это объект, и там есть нужная Вам инфа....сижу с телефона, пишу по памяти.

Comment: Зачем Вам FileReader, если имена файлов лежат в самом инпуте в массиве files?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov   тоесть его как то надо перебрать как в php но я фореач пытался так но не дало результата   var fl = ele.files[0];
 fl.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
 alert(item + " -> " + i +" -> "+ arr);
 });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672957/6119618
Mime тип нужно проверять. Иначе по видом .txt и других можно всякий шлак лить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
 ele.file[0].name.split(".").splice(-1,1)[0]
```

вернёт расширение файла